# DelphiJson - How to access multidimensional array?

Tags: json, delphi, multidimensional-array

I use the https://code.google.com/p/delphijson/ projects to parse JSON. It works quite good but I'm not able to access value of multidimensional array.

I have this JSON data:

```
{"B":[{"IDS":0,"WID":1,"W":15,"D":1,"SPRITE":14,"EQ":[[98,1,1,3,3,[[9,2106],[1,1720],[4,7326]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1],[99,2,1,3,4,[[4,2204],[11,7011],[7,701]],-1,-1,5,-1,-1],[1010,3,1,3,1,[[10,221],[2,3],[11,7122]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1],[101,4,1,3,2,[[11,221],[11,724],[4,717]],-1,-1,0,-1,-1]],"GUM":[],"PIS":0,"CID":2,"N":""}]}
```

I create a JSONObject:

```
var
  j,jj: TJSONObject;
  x: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
  // Create a new JSON object from a JSON string
  j := JSONObjectFromJSON(TFile.ReadAllText('data.txt'));
  x := j.B.Count; // Get count of B
  s := j.B[0].Wid; // Access WID from first B-item
end;
```

How can I access the value from EQ array? Eg. Values 98,1,1,3 and also nested array values from the sample JSON data?

Comment: I dont know this unit but maybe `j.B[0].EQ[0].SomeFunctionToGetItemAtIndexN`? I did use another project for JSON parsing. I liked it, can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/superobject/downloads/list

Comment: Each element has a `ValueType` property to know it is an array and each array has a `Count` property to know how many items.

Comment: Yes, this work at my example (eg. j.B.Count or j.B[0].Wid) but when I tried something like j.B[0].EQ[0].Count or j.B[0].EQ[0][0] I got invalid variant operation :-(

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not have support for multi-dimensional arrays. It has scalars, arrays and dictionaries.

What you think of as a multi-dimensional array is an array that contains an element that in turn is an array.

So, if you know how to handle arrays, you can simply apply that knowledge recursively. Iterate over the outer array. And then for each element that is an array, iterate over that inner array.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this JSON library handles these as variant objects and accepts pseudo properties like j.B.Count or j.B[0].Wid but I don't iterate an array. There is a function VarIsJSONArray and VarAsJSONArray, but it can't be used on j.B.EQ[0] - it doesn't match the array type.

Comment: It seems nice to me. It works fine, but I don't know how to handle this special case :-(

Comment: Really, use SuperObject, it's the json library of choice

Comment: OK. I try it. Can you provide me with short sample, how to access the values of EQ[0][0] and EQ[0][5][0]? Eg. array in array in array using the SuperObject library?

Comment: You are right, I can access the value using obj['B[0].EQ[0][5][0][1]'].AsString